# Escaping Mysql special character string with javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, string

I want to escape all mysql special chars in a javascript string.

the escape() function does not work since it doesn't escape characters like +

Any suggestions?

Comment: For Archive purpose: the accepted answer here works great http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744912/making-a-javascript-string-sql-friendly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the documentation on **binding parameters** in [Firefox's documentation for storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/storage).

> You should never try to construct SQL statements on the fly with values inserted in them.  By binding the parameters, you prevent possible SQL injection attacks since a bound parameter can never be executed as SQL.

```
var statement = dbConn.createStatement("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id = :row_id");
statement.params.row_id = 1234;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could AJAX it to PHP and return the `mysql_real_escape_str`ed value.

If you're escaping it for insertion into a database, you'll have to send it server-side anyway, right?

Comment: I'm actually coding something in Firefox, so it's client side

Comment: @Tony Like, with a local database?

Comment: @Tony [The first comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php#101248) on the PHP Manual's `mysql_real_escape_str` page has a good list of what values would need to be changed (and even how to change them). I imagine it would be relatively trivial to implement that in JavaScript.

Comment: Isn't the database in Firefox SQLite? **Not** MySQL?

Comment: @David I wondered about that, but how different could the amount and kinds of dangerous characters differ among SQL dialects?

Comment: Probably just enough to make it dangerous to try to use the documentation of a different database to determine it.