# How can I filter Emoji characters from my input so I can save in MySQL <5.5?

Tags: python, mysql, django, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a Django app that takes tweet data from Twitter's API and saves it in a MySQL database. As far as I know (I'm still getting my head around the finer points of character encoding) I'm using UTF-8 everywhere, including MySQL encoding and collation, which works fine except when a tweet contains **Emoji** characters, which I understand use a four-byte encoding. Trying to save them produces the following warnings from Django:

> /home/biggleszx/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py:86: Warning: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x98\xAD I...' for column 'text' at row 1
>     return self.cursor.execute(query, args)

I'm using MySQL 5.1, so using [utf8mb4](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html) isn't an option unless I upgrade to 5.5, which I'd rather not just yet (also from what I've read, Django's support for this isn't quite production-ready, though this might no longer be accurate). I've also seen [folks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8676005/in-php-how-to-remove-emoji-code) advising the use of BLOB instead of TEXT on affected columns, which I'd also rather not do as I figure it would harm performance.

My question is, then, assuming I'm not too bothered about 100% preservation of the tweet contents, is there a way I can filter out all Emoji characters and replace them with a non-multibyte character, such as the venerable `WHITE MEDIUM SMALL SQUARE (U+25FD)`? I figure this is the easiest way to save that data given my current setup, though if I'm missing another obvious solution, I'd love to hear it!

FYI, I'm using the stock Python 2.6.5 on Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS. `sys.maxunicode` is 1114111, so it's a UCS-4 build.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: UTF8 can encode non-BMP characters.

Comment: @SLaks: Yes, but the `utf8` MySQL charset cannot store them since it only uses 3 bytes.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

So it turns out this has been answered a few times, I just hadn't quite got the right Google-fu to find the existing questions.

- [Python, convert 4-byte char to avoid MySQL error "Incorrect string value:"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12636489/python-convert-4-byte-char-to-avoid-mysql-error-incorrect-string-value)
- [Warning raised by inserting 4-byte unicode to mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10798605/warning-raised-by-inserting-4-byte-unicode-to-mysql)

Thanks to [Martijn Pieters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters), the solution came from the world of regular expressions, specifically this code (based on his answer to the first link above):

```
import re
try:
    # UCS-4
    highpoints = re.compile(u'[\U00010000-\U0010ffff]')
except re.error:
    # UCS-2
    highpoints = re.compile(u'[\uD800-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDFFF]')
# mytext = u'<some string containing 4-byte chars>'
mytext = highpoints.sub(u'\u25FD', mytext)
```

The character I'm replacing with is the `WHITE MEDIUM SMALL SQUARE (U+25FD)`, FYI, but could be anything.

For those unfamiliar with UCS, like me, this is a system for Unicode conversion and a given build of Python will include support for either the UCS-2 or UCS-4 variant, each of which has a different upper bound on character support.

With the addition of this code, the strings seem to persist in MySQL 5.1 just fine.

Hope this helps anyone else in the same situation!

Answer (score 18):

I tryied the solution by BigglesZX and its wasn't woring for the emoji of the heart (❤) after reading the [emoji's wikipedia article][1] I've seen that the regular expression is not covering all the emojis while also covering other range of unicode that are not emojis.

The following code create the 5 regular expressions that cover the 5 emoji blocks in the standard:

```
emoji_symbols_pictograms = re.compile(u'[\U0001f300-\U0001f5fF]')
emoji_emoticons = re.compile(u'[\U0001f600-\U0001f64F]')
emoji_transport_maps = re.compile(u'[\U0001f680-\U0001f6FF]')
emoji_symbols = re.compile(u'[\U00002600-\U000026FF]')
emoji_dingbats = re.compile(u'[\U00002700-\U000027BF]')
```

Those blocks could be merged in three blocks (UCS-4):

```
emoji_block0 = re.compile(u'[\U00002600-\U000027BF]')
emoji_block1 = re.compile(u'[\U0001f300-\U0001f64F]')
emoji_block2 = re.compile(u'[\U0001f680-\U0001f6FF]')
```

Their equivalents in UCS-2 are:

```
emoji_block0 = re.compile(u'[\u2600-\u27BF]')
emoji_block1 = compile(u'[\uD83C][\uDF00-\uDFFF]')
emoji_block1b = compile(u'[\uD83D][\uDC00-\uDE4F]')
emoji_block2 = re.compile(u'[\uD83D][\uDE80-\uDEFF]')
```

So finally we can define a single regular expression with all the cases together:

```
import re
try:
    # UCS-4
    highpoints = re.compile(u'([\U00002600-\U000027BF])|([\U0001f300-\U0001f64F])|([\U0001f680-\U0001f6FF])')
except re.error:
    # UCS-2
    highpoints = re.compile(u'([\u2600-\u27BF])|([\uD83C][\uDF00-\uDFFF])|([\uD83D][\uDC00-\uDE4F])|([\uD83D][\uDE80-\uDEFF])')
# mytext = u'<some string containing 4-byte chars>'
mytext = highpoints.sub(u'\u25FD', mytext)
```

Comment: I had been using for years the incomplete regular expression, but this extended one appears to be working just fine and provides a lot more coverage for newer emojis.

Comment: The flag emojis are missing here. These are made up of two regional indicator symbols, which are all in the block \U0001F1E6-\U0001F1FF.

Answer (score 0):

I found out there another regular expresion that is able to identify the emojis. 
This the regex is provided by the team at instagram-enginnering blog

```
u"(?<!&)#(\w|(?:[\xA9\xAE\u203C\u2049\u2122\u2139\u2194-\u2199\u21A9\u21AA\u231A\u231B\u2328\u2388\u23CF\u23E9-\u23F3\u23F8-\u23FA\u24C2\u25AA\u25AB\u25B6\u25C0\u25FB-\u25FE\u2600-\u2604\u260E\u2611\u2614\u2615\u2618\u261D\u2620\u2622\u2623\u2626\u262A\u262E\u262F\u2638-\u263A\u2648-\u2653\u2660\u2663\u2665\u2666\u2668\u267B\u267F\u2692-\u2694\u2696\u2697\u2699\u269B\u269C\u26A0\u26A1\u26AA\u26AB\u26B0\u26B1\u26BD\u26BE\u26C4\u26C5\u26C8\u26CE\u26CF\u26D1\u26D3\u26D4\u26E9\u26EA\u26F0-\u26F5\u26F7-\u26FA\u26FD\u2702\u2705\u2708-\u270D\u270F\u2712\u2714\u2716\u271D\u2721\u2728\u2733\u2734\u2744\u2747\u274C\u274E\u2753-\u2755\u2757\u2763\u2764\u2795-\u2797\u27A1\u27B0\u27BF\u2934\u2935\u2B05-\u2B07\u2B1B\u2B1C\u2B50\u2B55\u3030\u303D\u3297\u3299]|\uD83C[\uDC04\uDCCF\uDD70\uDD71\uDD7E\uDD7F\uDD8E\uDD91-\uDD9A\uDE01\uDE02\uDE1A\uDE2F\uDE32-\uDE3A\uDE50\uDE51\uDF00-\uDF21\uDF24-\uDF93\uDF96\uDF97\uDF99-\uDF9B\uDF9E-\uDFF0\uDFF3-\uDFF5\uDFF7-\uDFFF]|\uD83D[\uDC00-\uDCFD\uDCFF-\uDD3D\uDD49-\uDD4E\uDD50-\uDD67\uDD6F\uDD70\uDD73-\uDD79\uDD87\uDD8A-\uDD8D\uDD90\uDD95\uDD96\uDDA5\uDDA8\uDDB1\uDDB2\uDDBC\uDDC2-\uDDC4\uDDD1-\uDDD3\uDDDC-\uDDDE\uDDE1\uDDE3\uDDEF\uDDF3\uDDFA-\uDE4F\uDE80-\uDEC5\uDECB-\uDED0\uDEE0-\uDEE5\uDEE9\uDEEB\uDEEC\uDEF0\uDEF3]|\uD83E[\uDD10-\uDD18\uDD80-\uDD84\uDDC0]|(?:0\u20E3|1\u20E3|2\u20E3|3\u20E3|4\u20E3|5\u20E3|6\u20E3|7\u20E3|8\u20E3|9\u20E3|#\u20E3|\\*\u20E3|\uD83C(?:\uDDE6\uD83C(?:\uDDEB|\uDDFD|\uDDF1|\uDDF8|\uDDE9|\uDDF4|\uDDEE|\uDDF6|\uDDEC|\uDDF7|\uDDF2|\uDDFC|\uDDE8|\uDDFA|\uDDF9|\uDDFF|\uDDEA)|\uDDE7\uD83C(?:\uDDF8|\uDDED|\uDDE9|\uDDE7|\uDDFE|\uDDEA|\uDDFF|\uDDEF|\uDDF2|\uDDF9|\uDDF4|\uDDE6|\uDDFC|\uDDFB|\uDDF7|\uDDF3|\uDDEC|\uDDEB|\uDDEE|\uDDF6|\uDDF1)|\uDDE8\uD83C(?:\uDDF2|\uDDE6|\uDDFB|\uDDEB|\uDDF1|\uDDF3|\uDDFD|\uDDF5|\uDDE8|\uDDF4|\uDDEC|\uDDE9|\uDDF0|\uDDF7|\uDDEE|\uDDFA|\uDDFC|\uDDFE|\uDDFF|\uDDED)|\uDDE9\uD83C(?:\uDDFF|\uDDF0|\uDDEC|\uDDEF|\uDDF2|\uDDF4|\uDDEA)|\uDDEA\uD83C(?:\uDDE6|\uDDE8|\uDDEC|\uDDF7|\uDDEA|\uDDF9|\uDDFA|\uDDF8|\uDDED)|\uDDEB\uD83C(?:\uDDF0|\uDDF4|\uDDEF|\uDDEE|\uDDF7|\uDDF2)|\uDDEC\uD83C(?:\uDDF6|\uDDEB|\uDDE6|\uDDF2|\uDDEA|\uDDED|\uDDEE|\uDDF7|\uDDF1|\uDDE9|\uDDF5|\uDDFA|\uDDF9|\uDDEC|\uDDF3|\uDDFC|\uDDFE|\uDDF8|\uDDE7)|\uDDED\uD83C(?:\uDDF7|\uDDF9|\uDDF2|\uDDF3|\uDDF0|\uDDFA)|\uDDEE\uD83C(?:\uDDF4|\uDDE8|\uDDF8|\uDDF3|\uDDE9|\uDDF7|\uDDF6|\uDDEA|\uDDF2|\uDDF1|\uDDF9)|\uDDEF\uD83C(?:\uDDF2|\uDDF5|\uDDEA|\uDDF4)|\uDDF0\uD83C(?:\uDDED|\uDDFE|\uDDF2|\uDDFF|\uDDEA|\uDDEE|\uDDFC|\uDDEC|\uDDF5|\uDDF7|\uDDF3)|\uDDF1\uD83C(?:\uDDE6|\uDDFB|\uDDE7|\uDDF8|\uDDF7|\uDDFE|\uDDEE|\uDDF9|\uDDFA|\uDDF0|\uDDE8)|\uDDF2\uD83C(?:\uDDF4|\uDDF0|\uDDEC|\uDDFC|\uDDFE|\uDDFB|\uDDF1|\uDDF9|\uDDED|\uDDF6|\uDDF7|\uDDFA|\uDDFD|\uDDE9|\uDDE8|\uDDF3|\uDDEA|\uDDF8|\uDDE6|\uDDFF|\uDDF2|\uDDF5|\uDDEB)|\uDDF3\uD83C(?:\uDDE6|\uDDF7|\uDDF5|\uDDF1|\uDDE8|\uDDFF|\uDDEE|\uDDEA|\uDDEC|\uDDFA|\uDDEB|\uDDF4)|\uDDF4\uD83C\uDDF2|\uDDF5\uD83C(?:\uDDEB|\uDDF0|\uDDFC|\uDDF8|\uDDE6|\uDDEC|\uDDFE|\uDDEA|\uDDED|\uDDF3|\uDDF1|\uDDF9|\uDDF7|\uDDF2)|\uDDF6\uD83C\uDDE6|\uDDF7\uD83C(?:\uDDEA|\uDDF4|\uDDFA|\uDDFC|\uDDF8)|\uDDF8\uD83C(?:\uDDFB|\uDDF2|\uDDF9|\uDDE6|\uDDF3|\uDDE8|\uDDF1|\uDDEC|\uDDFD|\uDDF0|\uDDEE|\uDDE7|\uDDF4|\uDDF8|\uDDED|\uDDE9|\uDDF7|\uDDEF|\uDDFF|\uDDEA|\uDDFE)|\uDDF9\uD83C(?:\uDDE9|\uDDEB|\uDDFC|\uDDEF|\uDDFF|\uDDED|\uDDF1|\uDDEC|\uDDF0|\uDDF4|\uDDF9|\uDDE6|\uDDF3|\uDDF7|\uDDF2|\uDDE8|\uDDFB)|\uDDFA\uD83C(?:\uDDEC|\uDDE6|\uDDF8|\uDDFE|\uDDF2|\uDDFF)|\uDDFB\uD83C(?:\uDDEC|\uDDE8|\uDDEE|\uDDFA|\uDDE6|\uDDEA|\uDDF3)|\uDDFC\uD83C(?:\uDDF8|\uDDEB)|\uDDFD\uD83C\uDDF0|\uDDFE\uD83C(?:\uDDF9|\uDDEA)|\uDDFF\uD83C(?:\uDDE6|\uDDF2|\uDDFC))))[\ufe00-\ufe0f\u200d]?)+
```

Source:
http://instagram-engineering.tumblr.com/post/118304328152/emojineering-part-2-implementing-hashtag-emoji

note: I add another answer as this one is not complemetary to my previous answer here.

Answer (score 0):

i am using json encoder function that encode the input.

this function is used for dict encoding (to convert it to string) on json.dumps. (so we need to do some edit to the response  - remove the ' " ')

this enabled me to save emoji to mysql, and present it (at web):

```
# encode input 
from json.encoder import py_encode_basestring_ascii
name = py_encode_basestring_ascii(name)[1:-1]

# save
YourModel.name = name
name.save()
```