# Python, Remove characters, such as emoji, that cannot be handled by UTF8 MySQL DB

Tags: python, mysql, regex, utf-8, emoji

How can I replace characters, such as emojis , that cannot be handled by a UTF8 MySQL DB?

The key is to ONLY remove those characters that cannot be handled. I got this code from this answer [removing emojis from a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33404752/removing-emojis-from-a-string-in-python), but it's removing too much.
(EDIT: This is the page that I got the code below from [remove unicode emoji using re in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26568722/remove-unicode-emoji-using-re-in-python))

```
myre = re.compile(u'('
    u'\ud83c[\udf00-\udfff]|'
    u'\ud83d[\udc00-\ude4f\ude80-\udeff]|'
    u'[\u2600-\u26FF\u2700-\u27BF])+', 
    re.UNICODE)

 my_text= myre.sub(r'EMOJI', my_text)
```

For example, this heart symbol ♥ can be saved to the DB, but is caught by the above regexp.

Comment: In case you're not aware, mysql can handle emojis with utf8mb4.

Comment: Yes, thanks! I definitely want to change it at some point, but can't right now take the site down for the hours it may take to restart the MySQL DB.

Comment: That code isn't on the page you link to: is it you that has converted it to match against 16-bit rather than 32-bit wide characters?

Comment: Ah! Made an edit. It was on another page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26568722/remove-unicode-emoji-using-re-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL's `utf8` encodes precisely the basic multilingual plane (BMP). Rather than specifically emoji, you need to exclude all code points from supplementary planes, since in MySQL these require `utf8mb4`.

Since you appear to be matching against 16 bit rather than 32 bit wide strings, a code point outside the BMP is encoded as a so-called "high surrogate" in the range `0xD800..0xDBFF`, followed by a "low surrogate" in the range `0xDC00..0xDFFF`. The corresponding regex therefore is:

`u'[\ud800-\udbff][\udc00-\udfff]'`.

♥ will not match this since it is `u'\u2665'`. I think strictly speaking it's only an emoji if followed by the variation selector `U+FE0F`, but either way it's safely in the BMP.

Comment: This seems to work, thanks! That left the heart and some Chinese characters that I tried. The regexp converted it into EMOJIEMOJIEMOJI. Will it always be 3 times?

Comment: @user984003: I can't reproduce your result, I get `re.sub(u'[\ud800-\udbff][\udc00-\udfff]', 'EMOJI', u'\ud83d\ude00') == 'EMOJI'`, just once. I used  `u'\ud83d\ude00'` as the input string because D83D DE00 is the surrogate pair for `U+01F600`.

Comment: You're right! I don't know where the extras came from! You answer works great. Thank you!

Comment: This answer does not work when Python is compiled using UCS-4. Use this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/13752628/984003.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> u"abcd ♥ \ud83c".encode("utf-8", errors="replace").decode("utf-8")
'abcd ♥ ?'
```

Comment: This gives an error "UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)"

Comment: Because @Quinchilion is using Python3. In Python2 that'd be `u"abcd ♥ \ud83c".encode("utf-8", errors="replace").decode('utf8')`

Comment: @SteveJessop You're right, thanks. Edited for compatibility.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time! This time there is no error, but the emoji isn't replaced. I went ahead and set the other answer as correct.