# Insert emoji character to MySQL DB from iOS app via Java

Tags: mysql, utf-8, emoji

I'm working as a DBA on mysql 5.5.24 servers. Recently we faced one issue in production when one user tries to LogOn from iPhone and its phone name was having emoji character in itself.

Currently, in our system we have utf8 charset, which supports 3 bytes, but as its phone name was having emoji (4 bytes), the registration failed.

As mentioned in this [link](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4#utf8-to-utf8mb4), we tried to reproduce same scenario in our development setup but still faces issues:

1. I tried after changing the charset of only that column in DB to utf8mb4 - No Success
2. I modified changing the charset of whole DB to utf8mb4 - No Success

Java Logs:

```
2013-01-08 11:21:54,547 ERROR [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] (http-0.0.0.0) Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x98\x84' for column 'deviceDescription' at row 1
```

DB Logs:

```
insert into deviceDetails (deviceDescription, remoteStatus, deviceStatus) values ('?', 0, 1)
```

Note: Charset at Java side is still utf8. Can it be an issue?

Comment: We are having the same issue -- as you can see what the problem is with 3 byte mysql column limits to 4 byte from unicode6 characters, you can do a 4 byte to 3 byte conversion in your java code that will resolve this issue. I am currently researching this myself and can post my result if/when I solve it. If you happen to have solved this can you help me out? thanks

Answer (score 2):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814293/how-to-insert-utf-8-mb4-characteremoji-in-ios5-in-mysql). Also make sure that your connection character set is utfmb4.

```
Db     characterset:    utf8mb4
Client characterset:    utf8mb4
Conn.  characterset:    utf8mb4
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query to insert:

```
insert into homeDetails (homeId, homeDescription, routerMac, routerSSID, arpMac, homeDetailTS)values (123,'des','mactest',convert ('EmotRS'using utf8mb4),'aprtest', now());
```