# Sending iOS Emojis through MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, ios, objective-c, phpmyadmin

I am developing an iOS messenger app and i want it to have the ability to send iOS default emojis through the app. I am using phpmyadmin & mySQL databases to handle the messages and i have heard that if one does not do anything all that happens when you send the message is that the emojis come back as "?" on phpmyadmin and on the other side. I believe there is is some setup necessary and i was wondering if any of you guys knew how to basically send emojis through a mySQL database in objective c and php.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Hey! This seems to be an encoding issue. I recommend reading http://www.objc.io/issue-9/unicode.html and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-applications.html

Answer (score 1):

As long as your application and database are both set correctly for the 4-byte Unicode charset (utf8mb4) you should be fine. Both phpMyAdmin and modern MySQL installations deal fine with this, but if your webhost is using an older MySQL you might have difficulties (I've just tested 5.1 which does not have it, and 5.5 which does).

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8109948/2385479 and perhaps also glance at http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Garbled_data for some more information to get started.