# How to handle iOS emojis in sql server database?

Tags: ios, sql-server, database, emoji

When saving smiley-faces sent from iOS phone into sql server it changes the emoji  to questionmarks like this ?? instead. this normal happy face :) works fine to save in sql server db but some others dont. Anyone else done this before and maybe could help me out or put me in the right direction? Thanks alot!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try to convert the column that contains emoji to utf8mb4 as answered in this post. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8109948/546954

Comment: This answer is for MySQL, the question is about SQL Server, there is no utf8mb4  in SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

you can encode the string with base64Encodeing ,then insert the result into database

Comment: This is a bad idea because you lose any and all abilities to search and index a column.