# LARAVEL 5 - Model truncate string on saving when has a symbol

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

When saving, the model truncate string when it has a symbol... Something like this:

```
"Example text with symbol like this ... The rest of string was truncated."
```

After save, the string at database is:

```
"Example text with symbol like this"
```

Anyone had the same problem?

Comment: make sure your database (and table columns are set to utf8_unicode_ci )

Comment: convert your string to appropriate html characters before saving?

Comment: Have you tried this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814293/how-to-insert-utf-8-mb4-characteremoji-in-ios5-in-mysql ?