# Add emoji / emoticon to SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, emoji, emoticons

I am trying to insert emoji / emoticons to a SQL Server database but it just stores `???` instead of the emoji / emoticons.

I am finding only help for SQL Server not MySQL.

I tried : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814293/how-to-insert-utf-8-mb4-characteremoji-in-ios5-in-mysql/8109948#8109948)

but not finding answers even not able to set with :

```
ALTER TABLE mytable charset=utf8mb4, 
    MODIFY COLUMN textfield1 VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
    MODIFY COLUMN textfield2 VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
```

SQL Server does not recognize this command. This is only for Microsoft SQL Server not MySQL

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Use [`NVARCHAR(size)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx) datatype and prefix string literal with `N`:

```
CREATE TABLE #tab(col NVARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO #tab(col) VALUES (N'      ⁉      ');

SELECT *
FROM #tab;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0cb61b8ea0fe850b3575bfbe67280cbe)**

Output:

```
╔═════════════════════════════════╗
║              col                ║
╠═════════════════════════════════╣
║       ⁉      ║
╚═════════════════════════════════╝
```

---

EDIT:

SQL Server 2019 and forward supports [UTF-8](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server/introducing-utf-8-support-for-sql-server/ba-p/734928) collation:

```
CREATE TABLE t(col VARCHAR(100) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC_UTF8);
-- column's data type is VARCHAR!
-- collate could be set on column/database/instance level

INSERT INTO t(col) VALUES (N'☢️');

SELECT * FROM t;
-- col
-- ☢️
```

**[db<>fiddle demo - SQL Server 2019](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1c73f88871bf048e762aed06e6874106)**

Comment: it was mistake i was forgot to update database changes it works after updating entity

Comment: @Yagnesh Please help me on it: I've a textbox in which user is able to type text like `Hi, This is test of emoji ☢️` and I've to save this record in table. Also once I pull this record from table and showing to client end must show same along with emoji. I've created column type as nvarchar(450)

Comment: It has to work, same way nothing to change