# How to insert special characters in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, unicode, collation, utf8mb4

Much like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39463134/how-to-store-emoji-character-in-mysql-database) in MySQL, I am trying to retain special characters such emojis into an `nvarchar` type column. However, any emojis are converted to "??". I have tried to reproduce the question's solution including changing column type and collation in SQL Server but haven't succeeded.

What I am attempting to do:

```
INSERT INTO TableName 
(Id, Title, Description) 
VALUES
(1, 'This is my title ','Here is a description with a  radio');
```

Where `Title` and `Description` columns are `nvarchar(255)`.

The resulting insert looks like:

```
| Id | Title               | Description                           |
|----|---------------------|---------------------------------------|
| 1  | This is my title ?? | Here is a description with a ?? radio |
```

Using this to create the table

```
CREATE TABLE TableName(
  Id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  Title NVARCHAR(255),
  Description NVARCHAR(255)
);
```

The database's collation is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Use a `N'Unicode literal'`.

Comment: Try:
INSERT INTO TableName 
(Id, Title, Description) 
VALUES
(1, N'This is my title ', N'Here is a description with a  radio');

Comment: Thanks! That was surprisingly easy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    INSERT INTO TableName(Title,Description) 
    VALUES (N'      ⁉      ',
            N'      ⁉      ');
```

Use the prefix string literal with " N' <"my strange text"> ' "

Try this "select" statement as well:

```
    SELECT N'      ⁉      '
```

Comment: This looks like you've copied some of this from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33938482/2029983), as the emoticons are *identical*.