# Only one emoji image display in my app

Tags: ios, swift

I am building chat app and need to send and receive emoji images.  I use following code to post data :

```
 let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://test.php")  
 let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:myUrl!)
 request.HTTPMethod = "POST"    
 let postString = " shareImageMessage=\(message)"
 request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

I can see my message with emojies in debug area as follows :

[image: Debug area output]

But only following image display in mysql database :

[image: mysql screenshot]

And following code from php script :

```
$shareImageMessage = $_POST["shareImageMessage"];
```

I couldn't understand why only one kind of image transferring.

Comment: You need to show the code you're actually using to insert the data into the database.

Comment: I don't see how your external database issue could be either iOS or Swift-related... have you debugged what the PHP script receives?

Comment: It could be a rendering issue. The place where you print the output may not have the correct rendering for other emoji.

Answer (score 0):

To send more than one emoticon in the same url simply convert the string you are sending to the server to a base64 and then decode it on the other end of the database. To Encode and Decode strings to base64 you can check this [Convert between UIImage and Base64 string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251340/convert-uiimage-to-base64-string-in-objective-c-and-swift/11251478#11251478). :)

Answer (score 0):

SWIFT: encode the message with base64 like so:

```
func base64encode(message: NSString)->String{
  let plainData = message.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
  return plainData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.fromRaw(0))!
}
```

usage : `let msgToPost = base64encode("born to be encoded ")`

then in PHP just use the famous `$decodedmsg = base64_decode($str);`

*this code worked perfectly for me*

**one more thing..**
make sure that your database column supports emoji, you can refer to the question for more detail about fixing the database emoji thing

[How to insert utf-8 mb4 character(emoji in ios5) in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814293/how-to-insert-utf-8-mb4-characteremoji-in-ios5-in-mysql)

Comment: Your function changed to the following format by Xcode and doesn't post emoticons : return plainData!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))

Comment: My MySQL version is 5.0. I tried alter table command but encountered following error "#1115 - Unknown character set: 'utf8mb4'"  . And also, there is no  utf8mb4 option in Collation drop down menu. I think it is related with MySQL version.

Comment: I think that version 5.5 is a must in order to use utf8mb4