# How to finally set utf8mb4 properly on MySQL?

Tags: mysql, utf8mb4

I'm losing my mind on this issue since yesterday.

I'm trying to convert my MySQL database from utf8 to utf8mb4. To do so, I followed those sites/threads : https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4#utf8-to-utf8mb4 , [Cannot store emoji in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39326125/cannot-store-emoji-in-database) , [Change MySQL default character set to UTF-8 in my.cnf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513773/change-mysql-default-character-set-to-utf-8-in-my-cnf) , etc.

My database seems to have a `utf8mb4_unicode_ci collation` as expected, and all her tables too.

Nevertheless, when I proceed `SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';` I obtain :

```
#With a Root access
Variable_name              Value
character_set_client        utf8                #expecting utf8mb4
character_set_connection    utf8                #expecting utf8mb4
character_set_database      utf8mb4             #good
character_set_filesystem    binary              #good
character_set_results       utf8                #expecting utf8mb4
character_set_server        utf8mb4             #good
character_set_system        utf8                #expecting utf8mb4
collation_connection        utf8_general_ci     #expecting utf8mb4_unicode_ci
collation_database          utf8mb4_unicode_ci  #good
collation_server            utf8mb4_unicode_ci  #good

#With a standard user access
Variable_name               Value
character_set_client        utf8                #expecting utf8mb4
character_set_connection    utf8mb4             #good 
character_set_database      utf8mb4             #good
character_set_filesystem    binary              #good
character_set_results       utf8                #expecting utf8mb4
character_set_server        utf8mb4             #good
character_set_system        utf8                #expecting utf8mb4
collation_connection        utf8mb4_unicode_ci  #good
collation_database          utf8mb4_unicode_ci  #good
collation_server            utf8mb4_unicode_ci  #good
```

I set a `/etc/mysql/conf.d/90-my.cnf` file like this :

```
[client]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysqld]
character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
init-connect = 'SET collation_connection = utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
init-connect = 'SET NAMES utf8mb4'
```

My MySQL version is 5.5.54, all set in a debian 7.

Does anyone have a clue to help me ?

Thx for your help, and sorry for my bad english...

**EDIT**

Fun fact : when I check variables in the in-line command, I got this :

```
mysql> show variables like "%character%";
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
```

While I still have `utf8` for `character_set_client` and `character_set_results` when I check with phpmyadmin (with a non-superuser access)

Answer (score 2):

When connecting as user `root`, `init-connect` is ignored.

Give your application its own login *without* `SUPER` privilege.

Then, to make extra sure, whenever establishing a connection from your app, do the language-specific method of providing the character set.  (Or execute `SET NAMES utf8mb4`.)  What app language are you using?

In case something else is going wrong, see "Best Practice" in [Trouble with utf8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)

Comment: Thx a lot for your concern. I just edited the thread to add character/collation stuff with a standard user access to the database. Results are better but still not perfect.
I took a quick look to your linked post, man your explanations are very good. I'll try those as soon as I come back from work. I'll tell you if anything work. (Btw I tried the `HEX(txt)` thing and the result is good, everything seems "hex-encoded" as expected.) Anyway, I keep you in touch quickly. Thx again

Comment: Hey Rick, here are the news : I set everything you mention in the "What you should do" part. The test of the data is good (no double encoding and every character is correctly recognize).
My problem is : I have question mark in the database instead of emojis (however they are correctly shown in my website). You wrote "The bytes to be stored are not encoded as utf8/utf8mb4. Fix this." How can I fix this ?
FYI, I'm using php.
Thx again for your interest. See you soon.

Comment: "explanations are very good" -- I hate to admin how many years I have been honing those explanations.

Comment: An Emoji went into the table as `?`?  That implies that you were not connected as `utf8mb4` _when `INSERTing`_.  It is not recoverable.  What do I need to clarify in "Question Marks"?

Comment: Did you see my last edit ? It appears everything is saved as expected in the database. I think phpmyadmin is misconfigured : when i log-in database with it, I have some `utf8` . When I check on my website with php or when I log in mysql with an inline command, everything is set at `utf8mb4`....