# Emoji encode mysqlquery issue

Tags: php, ios, mysql

I've this string in iOS app

**Cat**

then i pass this string in a POST request as parameter, but before i did:

`NSString *nNick = [_stringNick stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

Now in PHP I get:

**Cat%F0%9F%90%BC**

The problem is in mysql database there is a record with this string:

**CatðŸ¼**

Now if I pass the string in php without `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` there is no issue.

But in this case `select * from table where nick = 'Cat%F0%9F%90%BC'` return zero result.

How can I solve this issue without make an update to iOS app?

Thanks

Comment: Check this link [How to insert utf-8 mb4 character(emoji in ios5) in mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8109948/7677598)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your mysql table encoding to utf8mb4

Comment: This is hard to answer it depends on your content and especially the language incase it's English you shouldn't worry but I think old emoji records you won't be able to render it probably

Comment: but without adding percent escape in iOS, the mysql query work well

Comment: Try to test your database in localhost and see whats works for you