# How to display Emoji on my Web Broswer using PHP

Tags: php, emoji

I'm trying tp display Emojis from my database to Web Browser.  I tried to input emoji from my phone to my app and it is saved to database as 'ðŸ˜'. How can I display it to PHP as emoji like this . Thank you in Advance.

Comment: There is a php lib on github https://github.com/iamcal/php-emoji which may help here.

Comment: You may need to make sure you database collation is set to utf8mb4. This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814293/how-to-insert-utf-8-mb4-characteremoji-in-ios5-in-mysql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to configure your database connection like the following:

```
    $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'db_name');

    if ($db->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $db->connect_error);
    }

    $db->query("SET character_set_client='utf8mb4'");

    $db->query("SET character_set_results='utf8mb4'");

    $db->query("set collation_connection='utf8mb4_bin'");
```

And ensure your HTML file is UTF-8, have the following in between the head  tags:

```
    <meta charset="utf-8">
```

Hope it helps. Cheers!