# Symfony Doctrine: emojis are not stored

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to save text with emojis. However emojis are not stored in text. Instead of emojis I get `?` in database.

```
 # Doctrine Configuration
 doctrine:
     dbal:
         driver: pdo_mysql
         host: '%database_host%'
         port: '%database_port%'
         dbname: '%database_name%'
         user: '%database_user%'
         password: '%database_password%'
         charset: utf8mb4
```

Post class where I want to save emojis

```
/**
 * Post
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="post", options={"collate"="utf8mb4_unicode_ci", "charset"="utf8mb4"})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\PostRepository")
 */
class Post
    {
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="id")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=false, name="text")
     */
    private $text;

 }
```

Example

POST body

```
 {"text": "test  test"}
```

`text` column in database

```
 test ? test
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this by now? Would you mind answering your own question? I have set charset to utf8mb4 on tables and set connection charset to utf8mb4 but till I get ??? instead of emojis.

Answer (score 3):

I know it has been a while, but this solved it for me (Symfony 5):

- On `config/packages/doctrine.yaml`, under `dbal` you must add the key-value pair `charset: utf8mb4`. The configuration is documented here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html
- If that doesn't work, you must check that in `.env` (or `.env.local`) the `DATABASE_URL` isn't overwriting the charset. If it is overwriting it, you just change it to `utf8mb4`.

This is asuming that the database is in utf8mb4. If it's not (and you can't change it) you must escape the emoji characters.

Answer (score 0):

You neet to set `character_set_client` `_connection` and `_results`.

Example **MySQL** query may look like this

```
SET character_set_client = 'utf8mb4';
SET character_set_results = 'utf8mb4';
SET character_set_connection  = 'utf8mb4';
```

Comment: I need to change table from doctrine. I don't have right to run such queries in MySQL

Answer (score -1):

You might need to change your MySQL tables to charset=utf8mb4.

[How to insert utf-8 mb4 character(emoji in ios5) in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814293/how-to-insert-utf-8-mb4-characteremoji-in-ios5-in-mysql)

Comment: You are right! Now emoji works!