# Parsing string in nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am `uploading images` using `nodejs`

My `query` is like:

```
var user = req.body;
var imgurl=projectDir +"/uploads/"+req.files.displayImage.name;
var sql= "INSERT INTO users values('','"+user.name+"','"+user.email+"','"+user.user+"','"+user.pass+"','"+imgurl+"',now())";
```

Everything goes right, except when it inserts `imgurl` it does not `parse` it,

My `project directory` is `D:\node`
also I get it in `projectDir =D:\node`

But it will `insert` in `database` like:

```
D:
ode/uploads/canvas.png
```

I understand that it converts `\n` to `new line`,

So, my `question` is how to prevent this and what should I do for `both single and double quotes` `insertion`?

**Thanks.**

Comment: Out of all the answers below: `connection.escape(value)` is the best one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Escape them using `\` as such `\\n` or `\"` `\'` etc.

[Here's a related question that answers your query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744912/making-a-javascript-string-sql-friendly).
The method:

```
function mysql_real_escape_string (str) {
    return str.replace(/[\0\x08\x09\x1a\n\r"'\\\%]/g, function (char) {
        switch (char) {
            case "\0":
                return "\\0";
            case "\x08":
                return "\\b";
            case "\x09":
                return "\\t";
            case "\x1a":
                return "\\z";
            case "\n":
                return "\\n";
            case "\r":
                return "\\r";
            case "\"":
            case "'":
            case "\\":
            case "%":
                return "\\"+char; // prepends a backslash to backslash, percent,
                                  // and double/single quotes
        }
    });
}
```

You can store the `mysql_real_escape_string()` function as a separate module and require it before usage or directly insert it into the .js file that will be using it.
You could use it as shown below:

```
var sql= "INSERT INTO users values('','"+user.name+"','"+user.email+"','"+user.user+"','"+user.pass+"','"+mysql_real_escape_string(imgurl)+"',now())";
```

Answer (score 5):

You should consider preparing your queries using the '?' syntax (https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#preparing-queries).

```
var sql= "INSERT INTO users SET ?";
// Connection attained as listed above.
connection.query( sql, { name:user.name, email:user.email, user:user.user, pass:user.pass, image:imgurl, timestamp:now()}, function(err, result){
   // check result if err is undefined.
});
```

Using this pattern, node-mysql will do all the escaping and safety checks for you.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Uggh, escape all the backslash and quotes in your query string. Always use `connection.escape`

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection(...);
var userId = 'some user provided value';
var sql    = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ' + connection.escape(userId);
connection.query(sql, function(err, results) {
  // ...
});
```

Comment: Gives error like: `Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near`

Answer (score 0):

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
 host     : 'localhost',
 user     : 'root',
 password : '',
 database : '*****'
});

connection.connect(function(err){
 if(!err) {
  console.log("Database is connected");
 } else {
  console.log("Error while connecting with database");
 }
});

var message  = req.body.message;
var user_id  = req.body.user_id;
var sql = "INSERT INTO users(user_id, message) VALUES ('"+user_id+"', "+connection.escape(message)+")";
connection.query(sql, function(err, result) { });
```