# javascript equivalent of mysql char

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays, char

I insert a byte array to mysql using

```
CHAR(2,3,5)
```

I wanted to directly insert the character string so I tried inserting the result of

```
String.fromCharCode.apply(null, bytearray)
```

But I'm not getting the same result. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: Here is the array I'm trying on. I tried escaping with the methods at [Making a javascript string sql friendly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744912/making-a-javascript-string-sql-friendly) but the value inserted is not the same

```
[255,216,255,224,0,16,74,70,73,70,0,1,1,1,0,96,0,96,0,0,255,219,0,67,0,8,6,6,7,6,5,8,7,7,7,9,9,8,10,12,20,13,12,11,11,12,25,18,19,15,20,29,26,31,30,29,26,28,28,32,36,46,39,32,34,44,35,28,28,40,55,41,44,48,49,52,52,52,31,39,57,61,56,50,60,46,51,52,50,255,219,0,67,1,9,9,9,12,11,12,24,13,13,24,50,33,28,33,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,255,192,0,17,8,0,102,0,242,3,1,34,0,2,17,1,3,17,1,255,196,0,31,0,0,1,5,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,255,196,0,181,16,0,2,1,3,3,2,4,3,5,5,4,4,0,0,1,125,1,2,3,0,4,17,5,18,33,49,65,6,19,81,97,7,34,113,20,50,129,145,161,8,35,66,177,193,21,82,209,240,36,51,98,114,130,9,10,22,23,24,25,26,37,38,39,40,41,42,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,131,132,133,134,135,136,137,138,146,147,148,149,150,151,152,153,154,162,163,164,165,166,167,168,169,170,178,179,180,181,182,183,184,185,186,194,195,196,197,198,199,200,201,202,210,211,212,213,214,215,216,217,218,225,226,227,228,229,230,231,232,233,234,241,242,243,244,245,246,247,248,249,250,255,196,0,31,1,0,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,255,196,0,181,17,0,2,1,2,4,4,3,4,7,5,4,4,0,1,2,119,0,1,2,3,17,4,5,33,49,6,18,65,81,7,97,113,19,34,50,129,8,20,66,145,161,177,193,9,35,51,82,240,21,98,114,209,10,22,36,52,225,37,241,23,24,25,26,38,39,40,41,42,53,54,55,56,57,58,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137,138,146,147,148,149,150,151,152,153,154,162,163,164,165,166,167,168,169,170,178,179,180,181,182,183,184,185,186,194,195,196,197,198,199,200,201,202,210,211,212,213,214,215,216,217,218,226,227,228,229,230,231,232,233,234,242,243,244,245,246,247,248,249,250,255,218,0,12,3,1,0,2,17,3,17,0,63,0,247,250,40,162,128,10,40,162,128,10,40,162,128,10,42,148,58,149,141,197,228,246,112,94,219,203,117,6,60,232,18,85,103,143,61,55,40,57,31,141,93,160,2,138,40,160,2,138,40,160,2,138,40,160,2,138,40,160,2,138,243,207,0,248,187,83,241,31,139,124,105,167,94,180,70,223,73,191,16,91,4,76,16,187,229,94,79,127,245,96,254,38,189,14,128,10,40,162,128,10,40,162,128,10,40,162,128,10,40,162,128,10,40,162,128,10,40,162,128,10,40,162,128,10,40,162,128,10,40,162,128,10,40,170,247,55,48,89,219,73,115,117,52,112,195,18,238,121,36,96,170,163,212,147,210,128,62,87,211,117,75,173,51,246,135,158,91,89,74,180,254,32,150,214,64,122,52,114,78,81,129,31,67,199,161,0,246,175,172,43,231,79,132,246,86,126,37,248,193,226,79,16,45,186,220,216,67,44,247,22,210,200,188,163,203,54,99,108,30,251,3,245,233,245,175,160,231,18,52,18,8,164,242,228,101,33,28,174,237,167,28,28,119,250,80,5,138,42,165,162,92,69,105,10,93,76,179,220,42,42,203,40,143,96,145,128,229,130,228,237,4,243,140,156,85,186,0,40,162,138,0,40,162,138,0,40,170,211,220,67,105,109,45,205,196,139,20,16,161,146,71,99,128,170,6,73,62,192,87,155,234,95,30,252,17,98,232,182,243,223,106,27,179,184,218,219,16,19,235,230,20,253,51,64,25,63,5,174,225,212,60,105,241,18,246,217,183,193,113,168,164,177,183,170,180,151,4,31,200,215,179,215,201,255,0,9,117,207,23,105,82,234,182,190,17,208,161,212,238,46,140,38,103,152,31,46,16,130,76,2,119,40,5,183,28,101,191,132,224,26,246,175,10,107,31,19,46,245,200,225,241,63,134,180,219,61,49,149,183,207,4,203,189,8,31,46,0,149,243,147,129,208,122,230,128,61,26,138,40,160,2,138,40,160,2,138,40,160,2,138,40,160,2,138,40,160,2,138,40,160,2,138,40,160,2,138,40,160,2,138,43,230,31,11,199,227,239,24,105,250,198,165,166,120,195,84,26,222,157,114,187,244,183,153,227,70,13,146,48,75,132,7,42,227,97,92,124,189,121,160,15,166,93,214,36,46,236,21,84,101,153,142,0,30,166,188,35,197,26,237,199,197,255,0,22,218,248,71,195,151,51,199,161,66,75,223,222,170,157,146,129,200,36,119,80,70,23,61,88,231,176,53,207,106,126,60,248,145,227,86,159,194,54,182,150,223,104,230,59,175,236,193,146,235,247,72,121,119,178,5,57,228,130,7,108,246,174,131,64,180,248,191,225,143,13,38,135,163,248,79,76,182,137,3,98,224,205,19,76,89,142,75,146,102,218,91,234,184,192,3,28,80,5,255,0,131,145,89,120,127,196,191,17,45,214,68,182,176,176,189,72,149,166,147,11,28,105,37,194,140,177,246,3,147,93,126,139,241,107,195,58,255,0,139,7,135,244,215,187,150,225,247,136,167,242,128,138,82,170,88,237,57,207,69,60,144,7,21,226,250,63,129,188,73,175,252,66,215,124,39,170,235,107,103,53,202,46,163,170,180,11,189,102,108,171,129,180,109,4,134,159,253,208,115,140,224,87,75,174,71,225,191,135,63,27,124,46,193,87,78,210,109,52,182,50,56,70,115,185,190,208,187,155,0,179,18,72,25,231,242,20,1,239,146,203,29,188,77,44,210,44,113,160,203,59,176,1,71,169,38,184,125,47,226,199,134,117,159,25,31,13,89,75,59,221,23,100,142,227,98,249,18,178,130,72,86,221,147,208,224,227,7,177,228,87,207,223,20,252,108,254,44,241,101,217,177,212,174,46,52,56,202,125,146,54,220,137,194,0,205,176,227,146,219,185,35,56,165,208,124,37,170,120,123,197,30,6,212,181,40,146,8,245,93,78,7,182,140,182,95,98,203,17,220,195,176,33,198,57,207,92,129,64,30,219,241,223,88,187,210,190,29,108,180,144,198,111,175,35,182,145,215,33,130,109,119,56,35,212,160,31,66,106,166,187,227,185,60,51,240,159,195,113,218,59,220,107,250,174,153,109,21,178,110,221,32,102,137,65,148,247,56,39,143,86,35,222,184,15,139,58,246,177,227,91,205,98,43,91,53,139,69,240,173,201,138,225,252,223,153,228,119,242,131,21,207,63,50,182,48,56,4,228,243,93,23,193,159,11,220,107,215,22,254,52,215,85,38,75,104,18,199,75,137,211,133,16,170,160,144,118,227,105,3,253,173,199,131,138,0,185,240,33,181,65,171,248,198,203,88,187,158,123,203,91,152,99,155,205,152,201,137,1,153,95,146,78,121,81,207,176,175,109,175,31,248,65,255,0,37,15,226,111,253,133,71,254,141,184,172,143,137,190,55,190,241,70,177,23,129,188,31,114,175,36,187,197,236,203,42,162,182,209,184,160,114,70,2,133,98,199,191,79,80,64,58,143,132,94,57,186,241,222,139,170,38,174,99,146,242,218,227,14,137,16,84,242,100,31,32,247,229,100,31,64,51,93,99,88,120,119,193,186,109,254,179,107,164,233,246,9,4,13,36,207,107,109,28,76,202,163,59,114,160,103,167,79,90,241,159,128,23,31,217,222,55,241,38,129,20,144,221,66,208,249,130,234,34,118,191,147,38,192,87,253,150,18,147,248,10,191,241,175,197,55,186,174,160,254,12,209,188,169,97,134,213,175,181,7,71,228,121,74,242,24,219,176,1,84,55,185,42,61,136,5,255,0,217,199,76,72,60,47,171,234,185,97,37,213,226,193,130,56,219,26,2,8,252,101,97,248,87,171,77,175,105,118,250,237,190,139,45,236,73,169,92,198,210,195,108,79,204,234,51,146,63,35,249,31,67,92,159,193,63,249,36,58,31,253,188,127,232,249,43,135,109,126,223,95,253,168,116,150,181,120,228,130,198,222,75,69,150,54,220,28,136,38,118,63,131,59,47,252,6,128,61,151,88,215,116,191,15,217,139,189,86,246,43,75,118,145,98,18,74,120,44,122,15,208,254,70,181,43,193,63,104,191,17,219,181,166,155,225,168,128,121,196,191,109,159,158,99,1,89,16,126,59,152,254,3,214,189,191,79,190,135,83,211,45,53,11,99,186,11,168,82,104,207,170,176,4,126,134,128,41,107,190,33,210,252,55,167,127,104,107,23,169,107,108,28,70,29,129,57,99,208,0,1,36,240,122,14,198,175,217,94,218,234,86,80,222,89,207,28,246,211,32,120,229,141,178,172,15,112,107,196,117,155,91,255,0,140,95,16,245,29,21,223,236,90,15,135,100,146,25,74,182,93,230,59,144,54,59,146,200,113,232,160,247,53,119,225,86,175,168,120,91,197,55,95,14,117,195,33,16,25,31,74,145,161,216,36,64,206,204,71,114,24,101,135,92,97,134,123,80,7,181,209,69,120,86,187,123,226,79,31,252,64,214,116,237,15,196,23,58,6,143,160,70,209,220,92,71,51,160,105,65,108,150,218,71,86,86,28,156,0,132,245,224,128,123,173,21,228,191,3,181,239,18,120,139,64,191,155,90,187,251,85,173,188,169,5,164,239,131,35,16,9,112,199,171,1,148,193,60,242,121,175,90,160,2,138,40,160,2,138,40,160,2,138,40,160,2,138,40,160,14,103,197,158,51,209,188,23,167,165,222,179,59,168,148,149,134,40,163,220,242,17,201,0,116,252,73,2,188,1,252,61,227,111,26,93,235,158,37,240,182,145,45,150,151,174,74,209,201,110,46,82,51,50,100,18,199,121,25,5,134,73,29,216,129,198,107,233,107,189,47,79,212,140,38,250,194,214,232,192,251,226,51,194,175,229,183,170,228,112,125,197,95,160,15,2,240,174,157,241,91,193,186,88,177,210,60,15,162,162,177,13,44,210,76,141,36,173,234,199,237,31,160,0,14,194,183,127,225,33,248,229,255,0,66,110,135,255,0,127,151,255,0,146,43,216,40,160,15,33,248,125,225,255,0,25,127,194,205,213,252,91,226,157,38,218,192,222,216,8,49,4,200,202,92,24,128,192,14,196,124,177,243,147,214,189,39,82,240,246,137,172,60,111,169,104,250,125,243,198,54,163,93,91,36,165,71,160,44,14,43,86,138,0,228,225,248,119,224,251,125,100,106,144,248,114,198,59,160,0,93,177,98,53,199,66,35,251,128,251,129,154,243,111,218,15,80,155,73,213,188,23,169,91,237,243,237,39,158,120,247,12,141,200,208,48,207,226,43,221,107,231,47,137,190,33,211,60,105,241,83,195,62,30,136,173,198,159,105,123,29,189,196,136,120,118,150,84,89,20,31,64,20,12,250,230,128,52,124,23,240,250,109,123,224,198,172,240,222,183,246,167,137,93,101,121,46,179,180,121,51,146,185,192,39,230,195,18,220,253,225,233,207,173,248,47,195,241,248,91,193,250,102,140,175,230,27,88,177,35,231,33,164,98,89,200,246,44,205,143,108,86,204,16,197,109,4,112,195,26,199,28,106,21,17,87,1,64,224,0,59,10,177,64,30,39,47,194,175,26,69,226,205,122,235,73,241,76,26,94,155,172,94,181,204,207,110,95,237,0,110,118,81,128,7,77,236,56,113,154,196,147,224,15,136,236,239,230,143,75,215,172,26,206,226,17,12,243,79,27,44,219,73,5,192,80,172,6,72,236,192,144,72,39,4,231,232,122,40,3,196,46,190,14,107,122,6,179,166,106,126,3,212,236,180,249,224,179,16,79,45,211,57,51,75,200,105,54,149,117,195,2,62,94,128,129,138,191,164,124,62,190,240,183,195,223,25,92,106,207,5,246,189,169,218,93,180,151,22,251,156,178,152,155,10,9,80,114,88,146,112,57,200,244,175,96,162,128,62,102,240,54,161,226,239,22,248,82,195,193,126,27,63,217,214,22,145,202,53,13,65,135,93,242,59,109,7,168,225,128,192,228,243,200,21,216,207,240,22,11,89,116,251,157,3,196,151,122,85,229,172,6,57,46,99,136,179,202,231,118,92,21,117,41,144,197,112,51,192,3,215,62,209,69,0,120,31,140,126,24,105,94,11,248,93,175,95,188,243,234,122,196,203,8,146,250,224,114,51,113,30,118,47,59,115,220,146,79,191,56,173,93,43,227,39,133,52,79,135,90,117,188,55,198,231,86,179,210,225,136,90,136,37,25,153,99,85,218,88,174,220,110,28,156,244,233,154,245,219,171,75,107,235,73,45,174,173,226,184,183,148,109,146,41,144,58,56,244,32,240,69,100,197,224,207,11,65,34,75,15,134,180,104,228,67,149,116,176,136,21,62,160,133,226,128,60,255,0,225,189,180,158,18,240,182,189,227,191,19,220,172,45,172,50,223,205,26,166,54,46,231,43,199,247,152,203,192,247,90,206,240,197,197,215,138,252,119,31,196,221,126,75,125,27,69,178,141,173,172,5,204,138,158,106,144,234,50,204,64,255,0,150,140,115,220,240,58,26,245,111,18,120,126,211,197,58,5,214,139,126,210,139,91,165,80,230,22,10,227,107,6,4,18,8,200,42,59,87,1,109,251,62,120,58,11,152,228,150,231,87,184,68,108,152,101,157,2,184,244,59,80,54,62,132,80,6,175,138,62,47,248,115,67,138,40,244,201,211,92,191,159,136,109,180,249,86,65,158,219,153,115,143,160,201,246,175,21,240,238,149,107,226,223,21,120,145,188,77,226,56,188,51,109,45,247,159,123,97,44,226,38,158,67,36,132,160,222,192,101,14,225,146,14,55,14,57,175,160,180,31,135,62,19,240,198,161,246,237,31,70,75,123,173,165,4,173,44,146,21,7,174,55,177,199,212,85,61,71,225,63,130,117,109,74,227,80,189,208,196,151,23,50,25,37,117,185,153,55,49,228,156,43,129,201,244,20,1,147,63,143,124,7,240,243,195,86,246,58,45,229,189,236,113,130,176,90,105,243,172,238,204,78,73,102,4,129,146,122,147,244,7,165,114,90,134,129,227,175,140,115,91,75,170,91,71,225,237,14,38,47,12,114,134,105,27,56,249,138,100,22,62,132,237,24,39,21,233,154,55,195,63,7,120,119,81,91,253,47,67,138,43,165,31,36,143,44,146,148,247,93,236,112,125,199,53,216,80,7,15,240,231,225,250,120,3,78,187,182,93,78,107,249,46,164,14,238,201,229,162,227,56,10,153,56,60,156,156,243,199,165,119,20,81,64,5,20,81,64,5,20,81,64,5,20,81,64,5,20,81,64,5,20,81,64,5,20,81,64,30,65,241,63,226,59,219,221,79,224,141,2,9,229,215,239,10,91,52,129,112,145,9,87,248,78,115,191,12,189,176,51,156,228,87,39,174,120,50,219,193,26,223,194,253,57,22,41,47,31,84,47,119,114,137,131,43,249,182,255,0,142,20,28,15,166,122,147,93,63,195,40,142,163,241,115,226,6,177,117,35,73,117,107,117,246,40,201,60,121,70,71,0,99,216,65,24,31,67,79,248,247,157,59,77,240,207,137,96,63,233,90,102,168,190,82,158,135,112,243,57,252,97,95,206,128,61,134,138,40,160,2,138,40,160,2,138,40,160,2,138,40,160,2,138,40,160,2,138,40,160,2,138,40,160,2,138,40,160,2,138,40,160,2,138,40,160,2,138,40,160,2,138,40,160,2,138,40,160,2,138,40,160,2,138,40,160,15,28,240,156,98,195,246,142,241,133,141,169,49,218,203,100,183,50,70,15,13,35,121,12,91,235,153,31,254,250,52,159,180,76,139,255,0,8,54,155,6,225,231,62,168,140,137,252,76,4,82,2,64,250,176,252,197,63,198,126,26,241,141,135,197,11,127,23,120,51,75,183,187,105,44,188,171,165,154,117,85,119,229,126,96,93,73,27,124,178,48,122,167,231,14,135,224,207,23,248,171,199,176,248,151,199,214,240,90,199,96,1,181,176,138,69,120,203,129,193,1,93,176,1,249,142,78,73,192,233,64,30,207,69,20,80,1,69,20,80,1,69,20,80,1,69,20,80,1,69,20,80,1,69,20,80,1,69,20,80,1,69,20,80,1,69,20,80,1,69,20,80,1,69,20,80,1,69,20,80,1,69,20,80,1,69,20,80,1,69,20,80,1,69,20,80,1,69,20,80,1,69,20,80,1,69,20,80,1,69,20,80,1,69,20,80,1,69,20,80,1,69,20,80,1,69,20,80,1,69,20,80,1,69,20,80,1,69,20,80,7,255,217]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var field = [65, 66, 67]
var result = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, field);
console.log(result);
```

Works. It get 'ABC' as a result.
What's the problem?

Comment: I added the test array above, the two methods don't insert the same value for me, even after trying two of the escape methods provided at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744912/making-a-javascript-string-sql-friendly