# iOS UiAutomation - Predicate with Single Quote in String

Tags: objective-c, nspredicate, ios-ui-automation

I'm currently using iOS UIAutomation and identifying elements with a string generated from an external database that is populated with dynamic data. But iOS uiautomation throws a parser error when the string predicate contains a single quote.

Example:

```
UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().mainWindow().collectionViews().firstWithPredicate(\"ANY visibleCells.name CONTAINS '" + title + "'")
```

Note that if `title = "Todds Apartment"` this locator works fine. But if the string contains a single quote it throws the parser error. So for example if `title = "Todd's Apartment"` this wouldn't work.

Is there a way for the predicate evaluation within single quotes to contain a single quote?

Comment: Escape the single quote? try using \'

Comment: Thanks. Problem is that the string is a variable coming from a third party location that gets passed to the locator without me knowing what it is or if it contains a single quote. I guess I could always do a replace on the variable. Something like title.replace("'", "\'")

Comment: That was going to be my next suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This is really a question about sanitizing input -- escaping strings for inclusion in a query string of some kind.

You should check out [this question on escaping javascript strings for sql](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7744912/2063546).  You can probably solve your problem minimally by simply replacing `\` with `\\` and `'` with `\'` in your input string.

[Apple's documentation on predicates](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/AdditionalChapters/Introduction.html) didn't seem to offer any information about what characters might need to be escaped.