# Escaping knex mysql query statements

Tags: mysql, database, escaping, knex.js, database-security

I'm fairly new to knex and databases in general, so this is a beginner question.
I found no clear mention in the [knex docs](http://knexjs.org/) about this.
Are non-raw knex queries automatically "safe"?

Secondly, for raw queries, I have several raw statements similar to this:

```
var condition = _.map(ids, function(id) {
    return '`id`=' + id;
}).join(' OR ');

knex('categories')
    .whereRaw(condition)
    .select('*')
    .catch(_error.bind(null, cb))
    .then(function(res) { ... });
```

Would escaping the `id` in the condition with a function described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7760578/3248285) be sufficient to escape that query?
What else to look out fo in such a scenario?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All knex queries are safe, also the `knex.raw()` queries if you use parameter binding syntax where `?` are replaced with escaped values (http://knexjs.org/#Raw).

Query that you are doing would be better be done without raw as follows

```
knex('categories').whereIn('id', ids).catch(...).then(...);
```

If you want to use automatic escaping of column reference a.k.a identifier you may use `whereRaw('?? = ?', ['id', value])` which escapes first part as identifier and second part as value.

So with parameter escaping your example would be something like this:

```
var condition = _.map(ids, function() {
    return '?? = ?';
}).join(' OR ');

var conditionParameters = _.flatten(_.map(ids, function(id) {
    return ['id', id];
}));

knex('categories')
    .whereRaw(condition, conditionParameters)
    .select('*')
    .catch(_error.bind(null, cb))
    .then(function(res) { ... });
```

However I have to say that there is pretty much always better ways to do the queries in `knex` than using raw conditions made this way.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: raw has to be used in any situation where knex doesn't have query builder methods. e.g. using case -- `raw("(SELECT (CASE WHEN ... WHERE something = ?) as 'cool_column'), ['myvalue']")`