# Node js - How to return array multidimensional

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, express

I need to create an array with this structure:

```
[
 { 
   position: 2,
   family: 9404,
   part: [ 'article1', 'article2', 'article3' ]
 },
 {
   position: 3,
   family: 9405,
   part: [ 'article4', 'article5', 'article6' ] 
  }
]
```

So i have a form where i select the parts that i want and send the families to get url.In the getter function i do a for to get the articles of each family and i want to query a select of articles and a select of positions. After that i try to push each array to a main array but i can't, show me undefined. How can i do this kind of operations?

I'm new with node and express and this is the first time that i have to do that.

My code:

```
 getFamilies(req, res)
  {
    console.log(req.params.data);
    var parsedData = JSON.parse(req.params.data);
    var compounds = parsedData[0].compounds;
    var supplier = parsedData[0].supplier;
    var families = parsedData[0].families;
    console.log(parsedData[0].compounds.length);

    var position = [];

    var data = [];
    var parts = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < compounds.length; i++)
    {
      parts.push(request.query("SELECT st.ref, st.design FROM st WHERE familia ='"+families[i]+"'"));
      position.push(request.query("SELECT u_order FROM u_part WHERE u_familia='"+families[i]+"'"));
    }

    return Promise.all(parts, position, families).then(function(listOfResults)
    {
      //add parts, position and families to data[]
      var data = [];

      //console.log(data);
      console.log(listOfResults);
      console.log("done");
      //return listOfResults;
      res.render('view2', {teste: data});
    }).catch(function(err)
    {
        // ... query error checks
        console.log(err);
    });
  }
```

In promise just print the first parameter "parts" and if i put the `[parts, position, families]` give me promise pending.
And how can i put the data in the structure that i show above.

parseData:

```
[
 {
   "compounds": ["8"],
   "supplier": ["sup"],
   "families": ["9305"]
  }
]
```

Please teach me how can i do this kind of operations.

Thank you

Comment: can you share what `parsedData` looks like?

Comment: Promise.all takes an array as argument so you have to concat your three arrays : ``Promise.all([...parts, ...position, ...families])``

Comment: parse data insert into resume @Guig

Comment: before the promise.all? @MatthieuLemoine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Not sure why you're passing `families` to `Promise.all` `families` seems to just be an array of data from taken from the query
- `Promise.all` takes an array of promises in input, and you're passing an array of arrays of promises and of data...
- you should never build SQL queries like this. This is a big flaw for SQL injection (but that's another question)

So do:

`Promise.all([...parts, ...position])` or if you're not using ES6 syntax `Promise.all(parts.concat(position))`

and fix your SQL!

====

Final code could look like:

```
getFamilies = (req, res) => {
  var families = JSON.parse(req.params.data)[0].families;

  var positions = [];

  var data = [];
  var parts = [];
  families.forEach(family => {
    // see http://stackoverflow.com/a/7760578/2054629 for mysql_real_escape_string
    parts.push(request.query("SELECT st.ref, st.design FROM st WHERE familia ='"+mysql_real_escape_string(family)+"'"));
    positions.push(request.query("SELECT u_order FROM u_part WHERE u_familia='"+mysql_real_escape_string(family)+"'"));
  });

  return Promise.all([Promise.all(parts), Promise.all(positions)]).then(listOfResults => {
    var [partResult, positionResult] = listOfResults;

    var data = families.map((family, i) => {
      var pos = positionResult[i];
      var parts = partResult[i];
      return {family: family, position: pos, parts: parts};
    });
    res.render('view2', {teste: data});
  }).catch(err => {
      // ... query error checks
      console.log(err);
  });
};
```

Comment: How can then we can extract part and position entites from next `.then(result => )`?

Comment: now returns a Promise Pending: [ { family: '9305',
    position: Promise { <pending> },
    parts: Promise { <pending> } } ] @Guig

Answer (score 1):

You incorrectly use `Promise.all`, it takes array of promises

```
return Promise.all([Promise.all(parts), Promise.all(position)]).then(function(listOfResults){
  var partResult = listOfResults[0];
  var positionResult = listOfResults[1];
  var data = [];
  for (var i=0; i<families.length; i++) {
     var family = families[i];
     var pos = positionResult[i];
     var parts = partResult; // logic to extract parts for current family
     data.push({family: family, position: pos, parts: parts})
  }
  console.log(data);
})
```

Comment: ``parts``, ``positions``, ``families``are arrays you need to concat them first

Comment: Ok, thank you. I' using wrong the Promise. Now, don't show the position and parts... Print this: [ { family: '9301', position: [ [Object] ], parts: [ [Object] ] } ] @cevek

Comment: @user3242861 try to replace `data.push` with this `data.push({family: family, position: pos[0].u_order, parts: parts.map(p => p.ref)})`

Comment: works! :) but i need to pass all elements of parts. I'm trying this but not work: ... parts[0].map(p => p.ref, p.design)}); @cevek

Comment: @user3242861 then use just parts: parts

Answer (score -1):

`Promise.all()` takes an array of promises, it looks like you are passing multiple arrays.

Comment: Not array of function, array of promises