# Javascript Array to MySQL "In" list of values

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays, string, arraylist

I have an array where each element corresponds to an *alphanumeric string*, lets say :

> userIds : ['Ab526', 'shvx23', '23636dsd']

I want to convert it into such a format so that I can pass this list of strings to **IN clause of mySQL query** as something like :

> Select * from Users where userIds in '(...)';

I tried using **array.join()** and many other methods, suggested somewhere or the other but all in vain.

```js
var userIds = ['Ab526', 'shvx23', '23636dsd']
var ids    = userIds.join(',');
var query  = 'Select * from Users where userIds in (' + ids + ')'; 
console.log(query);
```

which results in :

> Select * from Users where userIds in ('Ab526, shvx23, 23636dsd');

If anyone could suggest a solution as how can I achieve what I want to, it would be of great help.

Comment: `var ids = "'"+userIds.join("','")+"'"`;

Comment: It gives escape character along with single quotes. Tried already

Comment: late to party, but your code output is different than provided result - it may be missing something

Answer (score 3):

You could map the [quoted values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html) and join later.

```js
var userIds = ['Ab526', 'shvx23', '2363\'6dsd'],
    result = userIds.map(function (a) { return "'" + a.replace("'", "''") + "'"; }).join();
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I think this is simpler: `var ids = "'"+userIds.join("','")+"'"`

Comment: you need to quote single quotes in the string as well.

Comment: With this solution too, m getting resultant string as '\'Ab526\',\'shvx23\',\'23636dsd\''

Comment: you may have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744912/making-a-javascript-string-sql-friendly

Answer (score 2):

You could use reduce on the array:

```js
var userIds = ['Ab526', 'shvx23', '23636dsd'];
    var clause = userIds.reduce(
                 function (cl , a, currIndex, arr) 
                     { 
                     return cl + 
                      (currIndex == 0 ? "" : ",")  
                     +"'"+ a + "'"+ 
                     (currIndex == arr.length-1 ? ")" : "") ; } , "(" );
    
    console.log(clause );
```

Comment: As a string it comes out fine, but when appending it to SQL Query string, it throws an error : error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near "(\'Ab526\',\'shvx23\',\'23636dsd\')'

Comment: I know it's trivial, but do you add a space between 'in' and '( ... ' ? Many of my errors in query concat were due to missing spaces.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code :

```
var userIds = ['Ab526', 'shvx23', '23636dsd'];
var ids = '';
userIds.forEach(function(entry,index) {
    ids += (index == 0) ? entry : ',' + entry;
});
console.log(ids);
```

Comment: this is exactly similar to what array.prototype.join() does.

Answer (score 2):

Or a simple one liner

```js
const userIds = [12,13,14,15];
const query  = `Select * from Users where userIds in ('${userIds.join("','")}')`; 

console.log(query)
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me for the same issue:

```
var myList = [1, 2, 3]
var listAsString = myList.toString() 
var queryList = "(" + listAsString + ")"
```

SQL Query is like so:
WHERE number IN queryList

Comment: Does not work for strings in array like in the question

Answer (score -1):

```
let tickers = ['AAPL', 'MSFT']
const inStmt = "('" + tickers.join("','") + "')"
```

This will give you the result inStmt == ('AAPL','MSFT') which can be later on used as:

```
const QUERY = `select x from Y where Y.z in ${inStmt}`
```

Please note, that if you have numbers, not strings, single quotes must be removed:

```
let tickers = [1, 2, 3]
const inStmt = "(" + tickers.join(",") + ")"
```

Comment: Can you edit your answer with a textual explanation of the code for future readers please?